# how to access all the data points of list in lists

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-computing

```
def agglomerate(labels, grid):
    clusters = labels
    while len(clusters) >1000:#need to have a stopping rule here i did manually
        # find 2 closest clusters
        #print clusters
        distances = []
        for i,row in enumerate(grid[:5]):
            distances += [(i, i+j+1, c) for j,c in enumerate(row[i+1:])]
        i,j,_ = max(distances, key=lambda x:x[2])
        clusters[i]=[clusters[i],clusters[j]]
        clusters.pop(j)
        grid = add(grid, i, j)
    return clusters
```

here is the code for clustering dataset

```
def add(grid, lefti, righti):
    for r in grid:
        r[lefti] = max(r[lefti], r.pop(righti))
    grid[lefti] = map(max, zip(grid[lefti], grid.pop(righti)))
    return grid
```

now in here i m getting clusters as lists of lists and want to access all the points in each cluster to sum up the data 
for that

```
def getPoints(a,l):
    c = a[:]
    if (isinstance(c, list)and len(l)!=1):
        getPoints(c[0],l)
        getPoints(c[1],l) 
    else:
        l.append(c)
    return l

getting recursion error as i call getPoints(a,l)

----> 5  getPoints(c[0],l)

6        getPoints(c[1],l)

7     else:

RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

since the dataset consist of 10^15 datapoints
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please use meaningful variable names; your single-letter identifiers make the code harder to understand.

I think you're confused about your list management.  You pass the value of **l** into the routine and alter it, but then send it back as the return value as well ... and then ignore that return value.

The first suspect for recursion depth is infinite recursion in your routine; where is the output from your logic trace?  For any such problem, one of your first tasks is to determine the call sequence that called the problem: track it with a debugger.  A low-tech way to do this is to put tracing **print** statements into all your routines, tracking entry, exit, and values passed.

Note that you have 10^15 data points; you appear to be trying to put them all into a single list.  Do you have enough RAM for this?  Since you didn't include the entire error message, I can't tell where the error may have occurred in the code stack.

You haven't described your data structure; if it's a relatively balanced binary tree (as the code suggests), then your tree depth is at least 51, perhaps a bit more, depending on the balance.  The second suspect is that the tree is unbalanced, and one branch is deeper than the default recursion limit.  The logic trace will catch this.